# Where can I find my completion percentage?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

My work colleagues and I were discussing this game, and I was asked how far I had got with the game.

As my game currently has three odysseys listed in my Quest sidebar, I wasn't sure how to respond to this.

It made me wonder how to find out how much of the game content I've completed. However I cannot find it listed anywhere in the game after a brief search.

How can I find out how much of the game I've completed? Either in main story odysseys or total content completion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you can check your game progression on the Ubisoft Club website.

https://club.ubisoft.com/en-GB/game/assassins-creed-odyssey/PC/stats/

On the stats page a column sidebar lists your progression on certain things within the game.

[image: Main story progression]

There doesn't seem to be an overall completion percentage though.

Comment: This is a small feature that Rockstar gets completely. In Rockstar Social Club, they list 7/9 main, 4/9 side missions etc. Wish more games incorporated this for completionists like me.

Answer (score 5):

If you're playing through Uplay, you can see a more detailed list under Statistics:

[image: Uplay Asscreed Odyssey Statistics page]
<sup>([source](https://forums.ubisoft.com/showthread.php/1948814-AC-Odyssey-Uplay-completion-at-98-any-suggestions). the same thread suggests this page can be buggy, however)</sup>

Apart from general statistics, it shows the amount of completion in percentages of the *Main Progression*, *Regions Discovered*, *Reach High Points Synched*, *Abilities Acquired*, and *Ship Upgrades*.

Comment: This is what's on the website, although good to know it's in the client also.